# Is there an Encoder for Map type in Java Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, dictionary, apache-spark-encoders

I am trying to create a custom Aggregator function producing a Map as the result, however it requires an Encoders. As referenced in
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Encoders.html, there isn't one for now.

Does anyone know a workaround for this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: In scala you can use the handful `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder()`, but it looks like it's a bit more complicated in java. You might find something useful [here](https://echauchot.blogspot.com/2020/03/how-to-create-custom-spark-encoder-in.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not exactly an answer, but if someone came here with the same question but in Scala instead of Java, they can use the `ExpressionEncoder`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder

// ...

def outputEncoder: Encoder[Map[String, Int]] = ExpressionEncoder()
```

For the original question in Java, [this link](https://echauchot.blogspot.com/2020/03/how-to-create-custom-spark-encoder-in.html) about how to write a custom encoder might help.

Comment: This works for a Map of primitives; do you know how to make a Map with a nested data structure? (for example, Map[String, Array[String]])

Comment: Unfortunately, it's been a while since I've used Spark, so I'm afraid I won't be able to help

Comment: Thanks, I asked my own question (and got an answer) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77684318/how-can-you-use-a-nested-map-as-a-buffer-in-a-spark-aggregator